# SQL query with WHERE and LIKE not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-like, where-in

Hi I am developing an android app.I have a DB table NUMBERRECEIVED with a field phnnofrmDb VARCHAR. I need to compare these db numbers with the phone numbers entered by the user in a textview.

This is what is the code I am trying

```
while (c.moveToNext()) 
{

    //phone number entered in text view
     **contactNumber** 

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Test", 0, null);
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM NUMBERRECEIVED ", null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0)
        {
          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT phnnofrmDb FROM NUMBERRECEIVED WHERE phnnofrmDb Like '%contactNumber' ", null);
          if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) 
          {
            phnnofrmDb = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("phnnofrmDb "));

            if(phnnofrmDb.contains(r_address))
            {
                Log.e("same","true");

            }
            else if(!phnnofrmDb.contains(r_address))
            {
                Log.e("same","false");
            }
          }cursor.close();
        } cur.close();
         db.close();
}c.close();
```

But the Log says "true" always. I may be going wrong in the query. Please suggest how to resolve this and the user may enter numbers like +9195******** or +44********** or just  the number like 81**********. How do I compare them excluding the + and country code(+91). Please Suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`PhoneNumberUtils` provides various methods to compare and format phone numbers.

In your case you can use `toCallerIDMinMatch` and `getStrippedReversed` functions.

You can look more into the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html).

---

Use `libphonenumber` library.

> Google's common Java, C++ and Javascript library for parsing,
>   formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers.

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query with:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT phnnofrmDb FROM NUMBERRECEIVED WHERE phnnofrmDb Like '%'||?", new String[]{contactNumber});
```

NEVER hardcode user provided strings in your SQL statement.

Comment: What does '||' signify in the query?

Comment: `||` is standard SQL and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) concatenation operator

Comment: Ain't '%?' and '%'||? same?

Comment: `'%?'` is a string containing a percent sign and a question mark. `'%'||?` is a string containing a percent sign and text read from SQL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing quotation mark at the end of the like expression:

```
"SELECT numberp FROM NUMBERRECEIVED WHERE phnnofrmDb Like '%contactNumber' "
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: what? everyone else had the same answer, and while there might be another problem, it's definitely a problem with the query... why do you downvote? why not downvote everyone else here? very strange behavior.

Comment: I just thought you didn't deserve +1 @jeet gave you.

Comment: fair enough I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed singlecot( ' ) in the query

```
Like '%contactNumber
replace with
Like '%contactNumber'
```

Comment: No this is not working.Can u suggest complete query for the comparison.